# Symfony Mercure (bundle) Cookiegenerator.php problem

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, token, mercure

i try to fix the Cookiegenerator.php file for generate a tokken with my JWT key but i have somes errors :

```
            <?php

            declare(strict_types=1);

            namespace App\Services\Mercure;

            use App\Entity\Channel;
            use Lcobucci\JWT\Token\Builder;
            use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac\Sha256;
            use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key;

            class CookieGenerator
            {
                private string $key;

                public function __construct(string $key)
                {
                    $this->key = $key;
                }

                public function __invoke(Channel $channel): string
                {
                    $signer = new Sha256();
                    return (new Builder())
                        ->withClaim('mercure', ['subscribe' => [sprintf('http://astrochat.com/channel/%s', $channel->getId())]])
                        ->getToken($signer, new Key($this->key))
                        ->__toString()
                    ;
                }
            }
```

Errors :

Expected 2 arguments. Found 0. (L 24)
Undefined method '__toString'. (L 27)

I tried to redo the file and pass some parameters to Builder but nothing to do... Basically the file uses the use use Lcobucci\JWT\Builder; I thought I understood that it was no longer used so I use use Lcobucci\JWT\Token\Builder; Someone would have any idea ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Could it be that you are calling the wrong method here: `->__toString()` it should be `->toString()` according to the [class](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/blob/5.1.x/src/Token.php#L9) you mentioned

Comment: Also the `new Builder()` requires 2 arguments an encoder and a formatter. According to the [docs](https://lcobucci-jwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/issuing-tokens/) something like this: `(new Builder(new JoseEncoder(), ChainedFormatter::default()))`. Please follow the official documentation and try what i sent you, and give feedback afterwards if you are still encoutering errors or if it works now

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments above, the [token class](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/blob/02f7c37b9d7941c2eda0a5ad831ecd73350995d2/src/Token.php#L64C40-L64C40) no longer implements the `Stringable` interface and also has no `__toString()` method (which would [implicitly implement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) it as of PHP 8.0), so the call to the magic string method:

```
 ->__toString()
```

now needs to be updated to this:

```
 ->toString()
```

Also the `Builder` instance now requires 2 parameters ([docs](https://lcobucci-jwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/issuing-tokens/)), an encoder and a formatter, example:

```
$tokenBuilder = (new Builder(new \Lcobucci\JWT\Encoding\JoseEncoder(), \Lcobucci\JWT\Encoding\ChainedFormatter::default()));
```